# Используется неверная таблица при запросе Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'laravel.main_models' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `main_models` (`login`, `pass`) values (admin, 123))

При помощи миграции создал таблицу `users`

Использовал migrate:fresh

Хз почему, но используется таблица main_models, хотя я ее даже не создавал и нигде не указывал.

**Файл Миграции**

```
 Schema::rename('main_models', 'users');
    
            Schema::dropIfExists('main_models');
            Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
                $table->id();
                $table->string('login');
                $table->string('pass');
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите, что у Вас в модели User, а точнее есть ли свойство

```
protected $table
```

Если у модели определить свойство так:

```
protected $table = 'users';
```

То модель обязана будет строить запросы именно к таблице с названием 'users', так же проверьте наличие этой таблицы любым менеджером (phpMyAdmin или Adminner)

Comment: У меня не было этой строчки кода, но я ее добавил и всё равно не помогло

Comment: Проверьте, ту ли вы модель используете, на самом деле без кода очень трудно что то сказать, пальцем в небо)

Comment: А что нужно вообще написать в Model? У меня там только  
use HasFactory;
    public $timestamps = false;

Comment: киньте ссылку на репозиторий

Comment: https://github.com/RecentForce99/MY_CODING/blob/main/Laravel.rar

Comment: Ссылка не рабочая

Comment: Извиняюсь, это private репозиторий был, вот public: https://github.com/RecentForce99/all

Comment: Как воспроизвести ошибку? Я заполнил форму, создалась запись в signups с тем что я ввёл

Answer (score 0):

Модель должна выглядеть примерно как в коде ниже. Обратите внимание на строчку `protected $table = 'users';` - она предполагает указания таблицы users для модели User

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable;

    protected $table = 'users';
    
    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'email',
        'password',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $hidden = [
        'password',
        'remember_token',
    ];

    /**
     * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];
}
```